# Invoice and transactions design

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I am currently thinking of how to design my invoice entity. 
Specifically when it comes to the invoice amount.

These are the options I have in mind, what pros and cons do you see?

1. The invoice entity does not hold the amount itself, instead it holds a virtual list with all the transactions related to the invoice and the amount is calculated and presented through those. InvoiceId as a foreign key.
2. The invoice entity does hold the amount and the transactions list(as a safety insurance I assume?), still InvoiceId as the foreign key.
3. The transactions entity does not contain a foreign key. Instead the amount is calculated from the transactions and stored in the invoice table. With some other reference to the corresponding invoice.

Currently I am using option number 1. But when I think about the future I realize that my transactions table will contain a lot of transactions. And at some point I might want to move those to increase the performance, without necessarily moving(droping) the invoice table. So number 3 would be my choice here. But, are there any other option that would be prefered?

Comment: #1 is my preference...add indexing on whatever you are grouping the invoices by (customer?) to address speed issues if needed.  As a later option...usually the heavier load is caused by reporting afterwards.  Look into creating aggregate tables and a nightly ETL process that loads a reporting server from your Prod environment.

Comment: Hm thanks. But imaging this. I have millions of rows in my transactions table. When I am generating invoices, for each user I loop through the transactions within a certain period, and for each transaction I set the foreign key. That is what I am worried about performance wise. Invoices are generated once a month and transactions are created every day.

Comment: Don't use a loop :)   If you are doing millions of records, a loop should be the last thing you want to put in here.  SQL is set based, 1 script to do all rows at once.

Comment: Hm ok, so you mean a trigger so that when a new invoice is created(inserted) it will go ahead and update all transactions with the inserted.InvoiceId in one go? Is that what set based mean? :)

Comment: Triggers tend to process one line at a time as well...but it will depend on your requirements when generating invoices.  Think of almost any other computer language as step 1, step 2, step 3, repeat all steps for each line.  Think of sql as step1 for all lines, step 2 for all lines, step 3 for all lines, done.  Take all transactions across a certain date period and generate all invoices in one script.  I'm actually having difficulties understanding what you mean by update the invoice id...you have invoiceID in the transactions table and after generating an invoiceID you update the transaction?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So the transactions are created everyday, invoices are created once a month. So once a month I need to bind the transactions to the created invoices. Every transaction also holds a PaymentMethodId(cash or invoice). So, generate invoice equals all transactions within a defined period(current month) that has PaymentMethodId set to invoice. Am I doing it fundamentally wrong here? Therefore the InvoiceId is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 4?

Given your setup, I would go with a three table setup here...lets get rid of the entire update idea for this.  Lets take 2 base tables...you'll have data fields, this is just name and ID.

```
Invoice Table
-InvoiceID

Transaction table
-TransactionID
```

Notice the lack of invoiceID?  We'll have a third table control that relation.

```
 InvocieTransactions
-InvTransID
-InvoiceID
-TransactionID
```

Now when you do invoicing, you are simply doing an insert into this table and not an update...and that insert can be done with one select statement that grabs all the transactions and associate it to your new invoice ID.

I added the ITID as a unique identifier for this table...it's optional, but I like having the unique number on the table so you can refer to one row in the future (mostly for troublshooting purposes, or perhaps adding in a new layer of reporting)

Make sense?  We can continue to talk through this if you would like

Comment: That makes sense. It might be a good solution. Just need to think if it affects other aspects of my transactions mechanism, but it shouldn't! Thanks. I will build on this.

Comment: One question, isn't the InvTransID field a unique identifier?

Comment: Yes...it doesn't need to be there, but I like having it...if troubles arise later on, having a unique number associated to each InvoiceTransaction record will help.  Remember to try to avoid updates when you are operating at the million lines level...it's actually a delete of the old and insert of the new.  Doing just an insert will save time.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I was more refering to why should I have two unique identifiers? You said that ITID was an optional unique, but then again, I can use the InvTransID instead?

Comment: Ah, my mistake....I put two unique keys on the table and forgot InvoiceID.  Ha.   Edditing answer...InvTransID is good for a unique ident.  You will want both Trans_ID and Invocie_ID in the invoicetransaction table